# Jquerym AJAX, IE7 script errors

Tags: jquery, ajax

First I should say I only started learning HTML,PHP,Jquery a couple of weeks ago and just as i've got a nice looking site I happened to take a look in IE7 and its totally useless, I generally use chrome or firefox so lesson learned there.

I get script errors in IE7 on this(explanation below) I get the errors whenever I click any menu item, specifically the FAQ one, I can't get the html to format properly here but feel free to visit the site and check it out.

Basically these are click events for a menu (site is www.romaniantranslate.co.uk) I've validated the javascript using jsfiddler.

```
    $().ready(function() {

$('.kwicks').kwicks({max : 220,spacing : 5});
$.ajax({url: "home.php",type: "GET",success: function(data){ $('#content').html(data);}});

$('#kwick1').click(function() {$.ajax({url: "home.php",type: "GET",success: function(data){ $('#content').html(data);$('#container1').height(300);}});});

$('#kwick2').click(function() {$.ajax({url: "faq.php",type: "GET",success: function(data){ $('#content').html(data);$('#container1').height(450);}});});

$('#kwick3').click(function() {$.ajax({url: "contact.php",type: "GET",success: function(data){ $('#content').html(data);$('#container1').height(375);}});});

$('#kwick4').click(function() {$.ajax({url: "testimonials.php",type: "GET",success: function(data){ $('#content').html(data);$('#container1').height(375);}});});

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Marc

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, use `$(document).ready` instead of `$().ready`.

Comment: Superb timing, I only opened the hosting this morning and just as I've posted this i'm having a nameserver propagation issue so I cant get at the site at the moment.

Comment: I used visual studio to debug it the line it was hitting was....<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: line 4 5 char as I remember which doesnt seem to make sense, although the other errors pointed at the click() binding hence me thinking its the ajax requests

Comment: On that note i'm off to bed been at this for 15 hours, I think you guys should be able to look at the site if you feel inclined to do so as its hosted in the states so your nameserver propagation should in theory be a bit quicker

Comment: Did you try my first suggestion?

Comment: Sorry Blender the $document.ready? Yep changed it, unfortunately i'm still waiting for full propagation I can get to the site now but not the ftp location, should be alright soon then i'll let you know.

Comment: Ok getting somewhere now, first I put all the pages through W3 validator to get rid of any stupid html errors. The FAQ script error was due to me having <a> onclick event which was onclick="testimonial();<----. Apparently you cant use a ; in the onclick. looking at it the script errors are actually html errors but getting reported wrong because of the ajax calls, i'll update as I find out whats wrong. I cant discount you answer helping though blender.

Comment: Ok all sorted this is my fault actually because I am learning HTML my syntax wasnt correct enough for IE, I was missing script type tags and I incorrectly nested UL elements and <br/> all of which made ie throw a script error (which it actually isnt)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed there are a few people asking essentially the same question across the web so I thought i'd answer on the off chance someone finds this.

When your doing:

```
$('ELEMENT').click(function() {$.ajax({url: "WHATEVER.php",type: "GET",success: function(data){ $('#content').html(data);});});
```

If there is an error in your HTML anywhere IE7 throws a script error pointing at the $.ajax call rather than the information your fetching. MAKE SURE you've got the call right with no extra comma's too.

I had scripts in the wrong parts of the the document too which is just a newbie mistake.

Also `$('#ELEMENT').height(100)` doesnt work in IE7 you need to use `.css('height', '100')` which is probably better practice anyway.

Oh and don't forget to delete browsing data each time you alter your page with IE7 even refresh doesnt appear to pull down a new page in all cases.

Thanks to blender for his initial pointer that got me thinking.